# Allow enhanced PINs for startup with Bitlocker

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, bitlocker

I use PIN to unlock a windows 10 machine with bitlocker-protected OS drive. Currently, only 0-9 characters are allowed in PIN. Following a [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679890%28v=ws.11%29.aspx#BKMK_unlockpol2), I enabled "Allow enhanced PINs for startup" in gpedit.msc. However, still only 0-9 characters are allowed. Why is it so and what else can be done?

Comment: Did you notice `Existing drives that were protected by using standard startup PINs are not affected.` in the link you provided?  Doesn't that apply to your case?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 1909 you can switch between regular and enhanced PIN by temporarily switching to Auto-unlock via **Change how drive is unlocked at startup** > **Let bitlocker automatically unlock my drive**. No need to decrypt the entire drive.

Comment: This worked for me but I seemed to have to restart at each step to implement the changes.

Answer (score 2):

#### However, still only 0-9 characters are allowed. Why is it so?

The setting you changed only applies to **new** BitLocker startup pins.

> Existing drives that were protected by using standard startup PINs are not affected.

...

> **Important**
>
> Not all computers support enhanced PIN characters in the preboot environment. It is strongly recommended that users perform a system check during the BitLocker setup to verify that enhanced PIN characters can be used.

Source [BitLocker Group Policy Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679890%28v=ws.11%29.aspx#BKMK_unlockpol2)

---

#### What else can be done?

You can decrypt the drive and then encrypt it again, which will require you to set up another password.

> Decrypting the volume means that BitLocker protection is removed from the computer and the drive is decrypted, which can be time-consuming. When you decrypt the volume, all of the information stored on that computer is decrypted.
>
> If you decide to turn BitLocker back on, it will either use the TPM on that computer or it will require you to set up another password.

Source [What is the difference between disabling BitLocker Drive Encryption and decrypting the volume?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-the-difference-between-disabling-bitlocker-drive-encryption-and-decrypting-the-volume)

---

#### BitLocker Group Policy Settings

> This policy setting permits the use of enhanced PINs when you use an unlock method that includes a PIN.

...

> **When enabled**
>
> All new BitLocker startup PINs that are set will be enhanced PINs. Existing drives that were protected by using standard startup PINs are not affected.

Source [BitLocker Group Policy Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679890%28v=ws.11%29.aspx#BKMK_unlockpol2)